# Cannot read data from a bound partition

Tags: docker

Cannot read data while following an example from docker documentation. Possibly, something is wrong with my docker configuration?

Create a container in accordance with this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-file-as-a-data-volume

`docker run --rm -it -v ~/.bash_history:/root/.bash_history ubuntu /bin/bash`

When I try to see the history from the container, I get a 'Permission denied error':

```
root@81076476fa68:/# history 
    1  ls -la ~/
    2  history 

root@81076476fa68:/# cat ~/.bash_history 
cat: /root/.bash_history: Permission denied
```

Is anything wrong here with the ownership of the .bash_history file?

```
root@81076476fa68:/# ls -la ~/
total 60
drwx------  2 root   root     4096 Mar  8 21:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 35 root   root     4096 Mar  8 21:14 ..
-rw-------  1 nobody nogroup 42996 Mar  8 21:06 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     3106 Oct 22  2015 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      148 Aug 17  2015 .profile
```

4.4 and 4.10 kernels both give equal results.

I am on Linux Mint 18.1. Here is some system information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux a 4.4.0-65-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 23 17:49:58 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ docker --version
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 3a232c8

$ docker info
Containers: 39
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 38
Images: 269
Server Version: 17.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/296608.296608/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 395
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 977c511eda0925a723debdc94d09459af49d082a
runc version: a01dafd48bc1c7cc12bdb01206f9fea7dd6feb70
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
 userns
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-65-generic
Operating System: Linux Mint 18.1
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.55 GiB
Name: a-dell
ID: IEJP:6N34:GFBS:VIOM:HDBW:NVOF:BH3E:HZFO:3SOE:AACN:VZCV:FSWZ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/296608.296608
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

**UPDATE**

I see that the problem is with file access rights/attributes. When I change my .bash_history's attributes in order to allow reading for everybody, docker containers can access it. Is there a way to share my file access rights with containers I run?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 3a232c8
```

It seems you are running the edge version of Docker, instead of the stable one (edge is 17.x, latest stable is 1.13 i think).

Running that same example in a box with Ubuntu and Docker 1.13, everything works as expected.

So my advice would be to use the stable version, unless you really need the use the edge one.

Comment: I see that the problem is with file access rights/attributes. When I change my .bash_history's attributes in order to allow reading for everybody, docker cann access it. Do you know a way to share my access rights with containers I run?